# jQuery can check only one checkbox but also unselect it

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have checkboxes that behave like radio buttons, so that only one checkbox can be selected within a group of checkboxes. They are grouped by input class.

But I also want to have the possibility to unselect the checkbox, which is now being prevented in my code.

How can I have all the checkboxes "unselectable" with this function? Thank you.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="fruit" class="classname">I like fruits
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vegetable" value="vegetable" class="classname">I like vegetables
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var $unique = $('input.classname');
     $unique.click(function () {
         $unique.removeAttr('checked');
         $(this).attr('checked', true);
     });
 });
```

[JSFiddle example over here](http://jsfiddle.net/e7w7etdz/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to handle only the select operation like

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $unique = $('input.classname');
    $unique.change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $unique.not(this).prop('checked', false);
        }
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5wLf02sj/)